# Query quick in production, became slow in past week in development

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks at all the lessons (o_id) the a user (m_id) has viewed, the last rating they gave it (first subquery) and the last time they rated it (second subquery)

the query is quick in production, but just recently on my development machine it grinds to a halt, I caught it taking **1800s** today.

```sql
SELECT o_id i , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mo_access_date) a, mo_complete c, mo_quizscore q,
  (
    SELECT mlr_rating 
    FROM member_lesson_rating 
    WHERE m_id=mo.m_id&&o_id=mo.o_id 
    ORDER BY mlr_id DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) r,
  (
    SELECT if(mlr_rating > 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mlr_created),null) x 
    FROM member_lesson_rating  
    WHERE m_id=mo.m_id&&o_id=mo.o_id 
    ORDER BY mlr_id DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) u
FROM member_object_tbl mo
WHERE m_id=64206
```

and the describe (

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table                | type  | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mo                   | ref   | opt_cols,m_id    | opt_cols | 4       | const |   99 |             |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | member_lesson_rating | index | m_id,m_id_2,o_id | PRIMARY  | 4       | NULL  |    1 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | member_lesson_rating | index | m_id,m_id_2,o_id | PRIMARY  | 4       | NULL  |    1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

profiling the query shows that each subquery takes over a second in my testing ... (ie 1*99)

and the create table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `member_lesson_rating` (
  `mlr_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `m_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `o_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mlr_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mlr_rating` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mlr_id`),
  KEY `m_id` (`m_id`,`o_id`),
  KEY `m_id_2` (`m_id`),
  KEY `o_id` (`o_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2882202 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Update:** new query that doesn't cause any issues

```
SELECT
  mo.o_id i , 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mo_access_date) a, 
  mo_complete c, 
  mo_quizscore q,
  if(mlr_rating > 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mlr_created),null) u,
  mlr_rating r
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM member_object_tbl WHERE m_id=?) mo
LEFT JOIN
  (  
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
      SELECT * 
      FROM member_lesson_rating 
      WHERE m_id=?
      ORDER BY mlr_id DESC
    ) mlr2 
    GROUP BY o_id
  ) mlr
ON mo.o_id=mlr.o_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependent subqueries are horrible at scaling; I think you can work around this by first selecting the maximum `mlr_id` and then joining it back to itself again to get `mlr_rating` dependent fields.

```
SELECT tmp.*, r2.mlr_rating, IF(r2.mlr_rating > 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r2.mlr_created), NULL) x FROM 
  (SELECT o_id i, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mo_access_date) a, mo_complete c, mo_quizscore q,
      MAX(mlr_id) AS max_mlr_id
      FROM member_object_tbl mo
      INNER JOIN member_lesson_rating r ON r.m_id = mo.m_id AND r.o_id = mo.o_id
      WHERE m_id=64206
      GROUP BY m.o_id
  ) tmp
  INNER JOIN member_lesson_rating r2 ON r2.mlr_id = tmp.max_mlr_id
```

Comment: i need the max mlr_id for each lesson (o_id) .. andding a GROUP BY to the subquery gives me this .... BUT doesn't help me with the differences between dev and production (unless its a version issue, 5.5(dev) vs 5.1(prod))

Comment: @BruceAldridge does it have the same amounts of data? It could just be a memory thing

Comment: @BruceAldridge if this problem didn't happen before with a similar amount of data in your development environment, it can't be due to SQL and you'd be looking at the MySQL instance itself.

Comment: same amount of data, both times 99rows, should be quick to lookup. I've rewritten the query and it works much better, just concerned about the underlying problem :/

Comment: What have you rewritten the query to? Besides that, I think you're looking at a MySQL instance issue. You can do 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' to see what's dragging it down I suppose.

Comment: i rewrote it to a mess of sql i didn't want to do so many queries, but i was getting errors until i did another nest. ... edited your answer by mistake and now can't revert the edit ... arrrggh  (it was too big for a comment)